# Many URLs linking to one page

Tags: url, joomla, hyperlink

I have a Joomla website `example.com` and a sub directory `support.example.com`.

I want to give a unique URL to my customers to view content which will be `support.example.com/customer1` and `support.example.com/customer2` and so on.

What I would like is that no matter how many customer URLs I have, it automatically points to `support.example.com` which will prompt the user to enter a username and password. I know that I can have a redirect in each directory but I don't really want to set up a physical directory for each customer, it's more of an alias. Also note that I have my hosting with 1and1 UK and I dont think that I can alter the `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I get it, but you can use a plugin on the onAfterLogin event to send them where you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with URL Rewrite. It can translate

```
 support.yourdomain.com/customer1/somefile.html
 support.yourdomain.com/customer2/somefile.html
```

to

```
 support.yourdomain.com/help/somefile.html
```

Even better, it can do something like this:

```
 support.yourdomain.com/customer1/somefile.html
 support.yourdomain.com/customer2/somefile.html
```

to

```
 support.yourdomain.com/help/findhelp.php?customer=customer1&file=somefile.html
 support.yourdomain.com/help/findhelp.php?customer=customer2&file=somefile.html
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any point to a URL Rewrite like this or is it just aesthetic? What is wrong with the version with the query string?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query string version. but there are reasons to use other format. try search "search-engine friendly URL". This original question is also a good user case.